React component Library - Rollup build folder and cjs file both contributing to nextjs build size?
I have created one react component library. To build the library using rollup configuration.
import Button from "ui-library/Button";
import Tabs from "ui-library/Tabs";
import Typography from "ui-library/Typography";

The individual sizes of each component are in few KB but they collectively increased the size to 10KB.
npm run build gives -

It gives 170 KB if I had used these components not from this library then the size was 161 KB.
When I check the chunk sizes -

We can see it taking the folder as well as the cjs file size. Shouldn't it be considering only the cjs file?
Also, is First Load JS size reliable enough for checking component size? When I take only Button component then size shows 169 KB whereas the component and its folder is only 2KB.
